# Avoid duplicate code when adding pre-filled checkboxes/radio buttons to your form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

When adding radio buttons and checkboxes to my pre-filled form I find myself having to duplicate code.

Ideally I want to declare via a vaiable if the input field should be selected or not. Like e.g.:

```
- checked = false # or `true`, `false`, `nil`, `""`
%input{:type => "radio", :name => "foo", :value => "bar", :checked => checked}= "foo"
%input{:type => "checkbox", :name => "foo", :value => "bar", :checked => checked}= "foo"
```

But the result is that whatever value I put into the `checked` variable it results in the input field ends up selected.

My solution results in lots of lines of duplicate code:

```
- checked = false # or `true`, `false`, `nil`, `""`
- if true
  %input{:type => "radio", :name => "foo", :value => "bar", :checked => true}= "foo"
- else
  %input{:type => "radio", :name => "foo", :value => "bar"}= "foo"

- if true
  %input{:type => "checkbox", :name => "foo", :value => "bar", :checked => true}= "foo"
- else
  %input{:type => "checkbox", :name => "foo", :value => "bar"}= "foo"
```

Anyone who know a better way?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, but why not just use your `checked` variable as the value for the `:checked` option in the input fields? Example: `%input{type: "radio", name: "foo", value: "bar", checked: checked}= "foo"`

Comment: @mmichael because your browser seems to ignore the value. If the `checked` key exists, the checkbox/radio button gets selected.

Comment: You should be using the Rails form helpers. In this case, the check_box_tag: `check_box_tag 'foo', 'bar', checked` where `checked` is your boolean variable.

Comment: Your first approach is the right way to do this in Haml and should be working. What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails API has a couple of helpers for radio/checkbox tags

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag